# Can world exist without Sanatan Dharma?

Tags: vedas

Since only in Sanatan Dharma, people worship devtas . Can world exist if Sanatan Dharma ceases to exist as once sanatan dharma goes extinct , devtas will not be worshipped , so they will get angry and might destroy the world.

Comment: There will be darkness of ignorance everywhere !!!

Comment: Devtas don’t have the power to destroy Earth, let alone the Solar System or the Universe. Only Bhagwan has the power to do this